# OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties in BizTalk

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013, operationcontext

Have to add OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties to outgoing BizTalk message
How to implement below code in BizTalk?

```
ConcurrentPrograms_ARClient client1 = new ConcurrentPrograms_ARClient(binding, address); 

using (new OperationContextScope(client1.InnerChannel))
{ 
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add("Property Name", "Property Value"); 
    client1.OPERATION(params...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [WCF message inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can implement one in a separate project and configure it as a behavior in your send port where you would then have full control over both the request and the reply message.

Comment: Thanks Pieter for your suggestion.I have created message inspector and added properties like below. During debugging, I could view properties. But After inspector an encoder component is called. But OperationContext.Current is null in encoder compenent. Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version); newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);

Comment: I mean, I am trying to access properties in custom message encoder which are set in custom message inspector through Operation context.

Comment: Sorry @rshaik, I'm not able to help you further on this. The Message Inspector seems like a logical choice for me, but I haven't done this particular thing myself I'm afraid.